# Cómo hago que una alerta no se muestre infinitas veces

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema en mi validación de formulario, me pidieron hacer un proyecto y tengo que validarlo con el plugin. jqueryvalidation

Este me permite mostrar el error pero con un mensaje, busque más y logré encontrar la forma que quería que se mostraran los errores pero mi alert es infinita, al darle aceptar vuelve aparecer y no se quita.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clienteformulario").validate({
    rules: {
        txtrut: {
            // required:true,
            minlength:10,
            maxlength:12
        },
        txtnombres: {
            // required:true,
            minlength:10,
            maxlength:100
        },
        cbocomuna: {
            // required:true
        },
        cboregion:{
            // required:true
        },
        txttelefono: {
            // required:true,
            minlength:8,
            maxlength:9,
            number: true
        },
        fechanaci: {
            // required:true,
            date:true
        },
        txtcorreo:{
            // required:true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 50,
            email: true
        },
        cbovivienda:{
            // required: true
        }
    }, 
    messages:{
        txtrut: {
            // required: 'El campo rut es OBLIGATORIO',
            minlength: 'El rut debe ir sin punto, pero con Guion EJ: xxxxxxxx-x',
            maxlength: 'El rut debe ir sin punto, pero con Guion EJ: xxxxxxxx-x'
        },
        txtnombres: {
            // required: 'El campo nombre es OBLIGATORIO',
            minlength: 'Por favor ingrese su nombre completo',
            maxlength: 'Máximo de carctareres'
        },
        cbocomuna: {
            // required: 'Por favor selecciona tu comuna'
        },
        cboregion: {
           // required: 'Por favor selecciona tu región'
        },
        cbovivienda: {
           // required: 'Por favor selecciona el tipo de vivienda'
        },
        txttelefono: {
           // required: 'El campo teléfono es OBLIGATORIO',
            minlength: 'Ingrese un número de teléfono valido',
            maxlength: 'Ingrese un número de teléfono valido',
            number: 'Ingrese sólo números'
        },
        fechanaci: {
           // required: 'El campo fecha de nacimiento es OBLIGATORIO',
            date: 'Ingrese una fecha valida. recuerde que el orden es AÑO-MES-DÍA'
        },
        txtcorreo:{
            email: 'Ingrese un correo valido',
           // required: 'El campo de correo es OBLIGATORIO',
            minlength: 'Ingrese un correo valido',
            maxlength: 'Número máxico de caracteres'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        alert(error.text())
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Imagen que se queda en esa alerta

[image: Cómo se ve en la imagen queda la alerta pero no me deja aceptar y volver a llenar los campos, no sé cómo lo puedo solucionar.]

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar la propagacion debes colocar la propiedad **onclick** y **onkeyup** en falso dentro del validate:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clienteformulario').validate({
        onclick: false,
        onkeyup: false, 
        rules: {
            ///...
        }
});
```

Comment: La había intentado anterior mente con esa misma propiedad pero aún así se crea un ciclo infinito, aún no puedo entender el porque reacciona así.

Comment: intenta retornar falso en la funcion submit